# How i can build net-snmp-5.0.9 in 64 bit in Solaris 10 ? what the run time option in gcc

Tags: gcc, net-snmp, solaris-10

I want to build netsnmp package in 64 bit in Solaris 10.

```
How i can build net-snmp-5.0.9 in 64 bit in Solaris 10 ?
what the run time option in gcc
```

Comment: [net-snmp on Solaris](http://www.lelle.net/stuff/installing_netsnmp_on_solaris.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./configure --with-cc="gcc -m64" ...
```